# How can I write an array of strings into a file.txt using system calls write() and open()

Tags: c, arrays

I want to write a predefined array of strings to a file.txt, like so:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *somestr[] = {"haha\n", "aww\n", "hmm\n", "hello\n", "there\n"};
    int filedesc = open("testfile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        write(filedesc, somestr[i], 24);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will create `testfile.txt`. Expected file content:

```
haha
aww
hmm
hello
there
```

But when I tried, it gives a weird result. Actual content:

> haha
>   \00aww
>   \00hmm
>   \00hello
>   \00there
>   \00aww
>   \00hmm
>   \00hello
>   \00there
>   \00testfihmm
>   \00hello
>   \00there
>   \00testfile.txhello
>   \00there
>   \00testfile.txt\00\00there
>   \00testfile.txt\00\00;4\00\00\00

Comment: Note that if the `open()` options include `O_CREAT`, the function requires a third argument which are the permissions on the file to be created.  An octal value like 0644 is appropriate.  Historically, 0666 was used, leaving it to [`umask`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/umask.html) and [`umask()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/umask.html) to ensure that public write permission (and group write permission) are not given.  Modern secure thinking avoids making things publicly writable even if `umask` is set to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assuming that all the strings are 24 characters in length. This is incorrect. You are reading outside the bounds and writing this to file.

Instead use the correct length.

i.e.

```
write(filedesc, somestr[i], strlen(somestr[i]));
```

Of course add the appropriate include file - this can be found on the manual page for `strlen`

Comment: Great, Ed. Now she doesn't even have to look-up `strlen` in the manual!

Comment: Whoa that was fast :D now i can sleep in peace. I will accept this answer after  minutes, due to limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make more clear and readable your code Here are my observation :

First thing when you are using `open()` system call with `O_CREAT` flag, you should provide explicit `permission`, reason for this is if you observe man page of `open()` written by Michael Kerrisk, **open() with 2 argument** and **open() with 3 arguments**.

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags);

int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

when you are `creating` file and writing/appending/truncating file using `open()` system call you should use `open() call with 3 argument` . as man page says

- `mode` specifies the permissions to use in case a new file is created.  This argument must be supplied when `O_CREAT` is  specified
            in  `flags` and make sure `umask` value is not set to 0.

Refer the man pages for this "The `effective permissions` are modified by the process's `umask` in
              the   usual  way";

and if you try to open a already `existing` file using `open()` you can use `open() system call with 2 arguments` as man page says *"if `O_CREAT` is not specified, then mode is ignored"*

So replace  this

```
 int filedesc = open("testfile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT);
```

with

```
 int filedesc = open("testfile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT , 0664);
 if (filedesc == -1) {
     perror("open");
     …exit or return or …
 }
```

Second thing, `somestr` is array of char pointers, each pointer can have any length. Instead of random no of characters (24 as mentioned), if you want to make it generic, use `strlen(somestr[i])`.

```
int no_of_string = sizeof(somestr)/sizeof(somestr[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < no_of_string; ++i) {
    write(filedesc, somestr[i], strlen(somestr[i]));
}
```